# What is the actual center of galaxy in this image

Tags: photography

[image: NASA picture of the day February 2 2022]

[NASA picture of the day February 2 2022](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap220202.html).

What is actually the center of the galaxy here? Is it the bright star or something nearby it?

Comment: The text the images comes with says the center of the Galaxy is in the center of the image.

Comment: @planetmaker ikr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This image is based on a combined data set from the [MeerKAT](https://www.sarao.ac.za/media-releases/new-meerkat-radio-image-reveals-complex-heart-of-the-milky-way/) radio telescope.  The processing is described in [The 1.28 GHz MeerKAT Galactic Center Mosaic](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.10541). This paper includes a replica of the image above (with a different palette) along with celestial and galactic coordinates.  I am reproducing the image below.  The direction of the center of the galaxy is located the intersection of the to galactic coordinate lines $l=0.0°$ and $b=0.0°$.

[image: The 1.28 GHz MeerKAT Galactic Center Mosaic]